# how to avoid enduser from giving urls in textarea jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I want to avoid user from submitting website URLs in text-area using (JQuery) client side validation. I am using [Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plug-in.

Example:

http://www.example.com

I need to validate when user types http:// or www in text-area

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom function with a matching regex like this:

```
 $.validator.addMethod('no_url', function validatePositionNummer(value){

            var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$/;
            var trimmed = trim(value);
            if( trimmed == ''){
                return true;
            }
                return trimmed.match(re);

        },"No URLs allowed!");
```

Then you just add your new custom validation method to the element:

```
 $("#your_form").validate({ 
textarea: no_url 
});
```

You would have to fine-tune the regex ofcourse.

Comment: Why explicit upper and lower case instead of a case-insensitive match? You won't match CoM with that (or BIZ, museum, or any CCTLD for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

URLs or Links? There is a difference.

However, in either case, don't forget to check on the backend too. You can't trust client side validation. It should only be used to make the user's life easier.

Comment: I am validating in back-end using php. I need to check only in front-end.. 

Examples: http://www.example.com i want to avoid this Link

Answer (score 1):

@BernardMarx Thanks for the solution.

Here i used extra regex to validate protocols according to my requirement. Now i need to validate at the end. suggestion please..

For Example:

http://www.example.com/index.php

http://www.example.php/home/

```
$.validator.addMethod('no_url', function validatePositionNummer(value){

    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\:\\]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$/;

    var  re1 = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/; 

    var trimmed = $.trim(value);

    if( trimmed == '' ){

       return true;
    }

    if( trimmed.match(re) == null && re1.test(trimmed) == false){

       return true;
    }

},"No URLs allowed!");
```